# Switching up a JQuery slider - default value to 50%

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

**Does anyone know how I can change my JQuery slider default value to 50%?**

You can see the slider by heading to: http://www.workbooks.com/sales-performance-calculator and clicking "Get started now".

[image: slider image]

The code (I believe) is the following:

```
 if(@$value['type'] == "percentage"){
        $array = wb_spc_form_element_select_percentage();
        $array["#title"] = $value['title'];
        $array['#attributes']['class'] = array("wb_spc_percentage");
        $array['#default_value'] = empty($form_state['storage']['values']['step1'][$key]) ? '' : $form_state['storage']['values']['step1'][$key];
```

The custom module has a few other sliders, you can see the full code at: http://jsfiddle.net/40c02cfv/

In the HTML field you see: .module and in CSS field you can see values.php

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: Maybe `.ui-slider-handle{left:50%;}`. have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks, where would I add this?

Comment: It is `CSS`. `style.css` is the most common name of this file.

Comment: I don't believe this would work in this case. As it's a PHP form. Other sliders already have default values not using this method.

Comment: It is just a style, even if it is using PHP form of not, it doesn't matter. They are styled somehow (CSS).

Comment: I just tried this using internal css. But no luck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.

On line 172 of my JSFiddle you'll see the following:

```
 if(@$value['type'] == "percentage"){
    $array = wb_spc_form_element_select_percentage();
    $array["#title"] = $value['title'];
    $array['#attributes']['class'] = array("wb_spc_percentage");
    $array['#default_value'] = empty($form_state['storage']['values']['step1'][$key]) ? '50' : $form_state['storage']['values']['step1'][$key];
```

It was as simple as adding in `50` into the quote marks.

Worked a treat! Thanks for all your answers,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

the value gives the default:
http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-value

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks, how/where would I add this in?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value: 50,
      min: 0, 
      max: 100,
      step: 1, 
      slide: function(event, ui){
        $("#edit-varprice").val(ui.value + ".00");
      }  
    });
    
    $( "#edit-varprice" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) + ".00");
  });
```

```html
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    
  


</head>
<div id="slider"></div><br />
<p>
    <label for="edit-varprice">Percentage:</label>
    <input type="text" id="edit-varprice" />
</p>
```

Basically you need to pass value:50 which can be set by default as you need.

Comment: Thank-you this works well, what would I need to add into my code to make this work?

Comment: Just set default ` value: 50,` in your jquery

Comment: Like so:

    $array['#default_value'] = empty($form_state['storage']['value:     50']['step1'][$key]) ? ''

Comment: @Sam no when you're initializing your Jquery like I have posted in my answer please check that

Comment: Thanks, I'm terribly sorry. I'm totally new to .PHP could you take a look at the JSfiddle and point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Sam you need to do the same which I posted in answer